# Cocoa : Can Sparkle update auxiliary files outside the Application bundle?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, sparkle

Hello I am using the sparkle update framework for a project. Does anybody knows if there is a chance I can update the project accompanying database that is located in /Application Support/ AND the application itself ?
Any help will be greatly appreciated.
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sparke's design allows replacing only the application bundle. What I'd recommend is to save the current application version in the database, and when the new version starts it compares the saved version with the current one and do any necessary updates if needed.

Comment: Thanks a lot that is what I also think. My problem is that my database is very big, so I would like to provide some updates that include a new database, and some updates that only update the app. I believe I will have to do this manually. Thanks again.